# Exceptions for invalid files/ filenames that already exist in database

Tags: arcpy, error-000210

The script below is functional, but it runs into issues if it comes across duplicate files (even when overwriteOutput=True) and corrupt shapefiles when running feature to feature.

Are there exceptions I can add that will either skip these features if they already exist in the database, or continue running the script if it runs into an error adding a shapefile to a geodatabasing?

This is the script that I am trying to add the error handling to. The script performs the following actions:

1. Walk through a directory and compile a list of shapefiles
2. Add the shapefiles to a geodatabase

---

```
import arcpy, os, fnmatch
from arcpy import env

env.overwriteOutput=True

rootDir = "whatever directory"
search = "whatever criteria"
outGDB = "whatever GDB"

shpLst = []
    for root, dirs., files in os.walk(rootDir, topdown=True):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, search):
            shpLst.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

for fc in shpLst:
    date = os.path.basename(fc).split("_")[0]
    outName = os.path.basename(fc)[9:].replace(".shp", "_") + date
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_management(fc, outGDB, outName, "", "", "")
    print outName + " sent to " + outGDB
```

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?  What precisely does it do "wrong" when you run it?  What do you mean by "databasing a feature"?

Comment: It traverses a directory tree looking for specific shapefiles, and sends them to a file gdb.  If it runs into a shapefile that is corrupt, it tries to database it anyways and the tool fails, rather than skipping it.  checking/repairing geometry didn't work.  Also, if something is already in the database with that name, it fails rather than overwriting it.  Specifically error 000210 Cannot create output

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with these details.  At the moment you are describing two problems with your current code.  I think you should focus this question on the one about dealing with two final datasets of the same name.  I also think that you should undelete and edit [your question about invalid shapefiles](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195267/traverse-directory-tree-want-to-skip-invalid-shapefiles-pythonically) so that we can complete processing it because that seems to be your second problem/question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Exists (arcpy)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000069000000) to check for duplicates in your geodatabase. For example:

```
import arcpy, os, fnmatch
from arcpy import env

env.overwriteOutput=True

rootDir = "whatever directory"
search = "whatever criteria"
outGDB = "whatever GDB"

shpLst = []
for root, dirs., files in os.walk(rootDir, topdown=True):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, search):
        shpLst.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

for fc in shpLst:
    date = os.path.basename(fc).split("_")[0]
    outName = os.path.basename(fc)[9:].replace(".shp", "_") + date
    if not arcpy.Exists(os.path.join(outGDB, outName)):
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_management(fc, outGDB, outName, "", "", "")
        print outName + " sent to " + outGDB
    else:
        print "%s exists already, moving on..." % outName
```